# How do i read part of a function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf.io.read_file reads an entire file.  Is there any way to read just part of a file in tensorflow?  I want to do this for performance reasons.  Specifically, the tensorflow equivalent of:

```
f = open(fn, "rb")  
f.seek(file_offset, os.SEEK_SET)
data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='uint16', count=c)
f.close()
```

Comment: Why do you need tensorflow equivalent? Tensorflow IO is meant for operation on batches of data rather then "seeking". Getting the right offset could be troublesome with protobuf.

Comment: Sorry typo.  I want to know how i read part of *file*

Comment: What is this file? `TFRecord`? Something else? Why it needs to be loaded with a Tensorflow routine?

Comment: I want to do data augmentation inside Tensorflow for NN training.    I have large binary files, and only need a fraction (~10%) of each file, with the offsets changing randomly.  I can do it outside tensorflow but I think if I do it in the session I will improve speed. I am using batches and the read operation is repeated for each file in the batch.  Since the batch size is fixed I can loop in tensorflow to load the whole batch.  I could just load each file in Tensorflow and then crop it.  If there no way to read just the part that I want to get better speed?